# Use explode on array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What's the easiest way to turn the array

```
[
    0 => "3.1"
    1 => "2.1"
]
```

into

```
[
    ['tag_id' => 3, 'contact_id' => 1],
    ['tag_id' => 2, 'contact_id' => 1]
]
```

Is there something built-in with laravel/collections that I can use?

I know I can make a foreach loop and use explode and populate a new array, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in function in PHP or a laravel collections method I can use.

Comment: Which slow method did you use?

Comment: @RiggsFolly What do you mean?

Comment: add more details in question like what you have already tried

Comment: @TahirRaza Added more info. Please let me know if the question is unclear. The first section is what I have, the second section is what I want.

Comment: I'll just use a foreach then.

Comment: You could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (PHP) or [map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) (Laravel collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`combine`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-combine) (or the PHP equivalent [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php))

```
$keys = collect([ 'tag_id', 'contact_id' ]); 
$result = collect([
    "3.1",
    "2.1"
])->filter(function ($str) { return Str::contains($str, '.'); })
->map(function ($str) use ($keys) {
   return $keys->combine(collect(explode('.', $str))->take(2));
});
```

Comment: Although I get nested collections so maybe a `->toArray()` is in place too.

Comment: @SeaBass Do you really think this is easier and or quicker than a simple foreach ? For a start, how many functions needed to be called to achieve this

Comment: I guess I was looking for a simple laravel collections command for it all and we're getting to the same amount of code lol, but this has an added filter on it and the power of collections. Slower, probably, but we're talking about an array with max 100 items so should be fine.